# Can i increase my weblogic 8 license for more than 3 user

Tags: simultaneous, weblogic8.x

I am using weblogic 8 in my project. My deployed folder is accessed by only 3 user simultaneously. fourth user is unable to access that url. and getting 403 error.

Error is:

> The Server is not licensed for this
>   operation.

What is the solution for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the solution for this??

Pay more money.

Comment: :-) Thanks taspeotis for reply. Is this error is actually because of license or i miss some setting before depolying. 3 user is very less. :-(